# Using RegExp concepts, how can I write a function that accepts a string that returns another string with all the capital letters joined together?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example:

```
capitalSentence("The Cat In The Hat") // "TCITH"
capitalSentence("And I Think to Myself What a Wonderful World") // "AITMWWW"
```

So far, I have:

```
function capitalSentence(string) {
    var regex = new RegExp(`^[^A-Z]+`, 'g')
    var result = regex.exec(string);
    console.log(result);
}
```

I think I have the regex down but I have trouble trying to code the results into another string. I tried `push`, `exec`, and `concat` but those wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

We can try doing a global regex replacement on the pattern `\s*[a-z]*\s*`, replacing with empty string, to leave behind only the leading capital letters of every word.

```js
var input = "And I Think to Myself What a Wonderful World";
var output = input.replace(/\s*[a-z]*\s*/g, "");
console.log(output);
```

This answer assumes, though, that every word would contain at most uppercase letter, at the very start of every word.  For a more robust solution, we can try finding all matches of `(?<!\S)[A-Z]`, then join the matching uppercase characters together.

```js
var re = /(?<!\S)[A-Z]/g;
var input = "And I THINK to Myself What a WonderFul World";
var output = "";
var m;

do {
    m = re.exec(input);
    if (m) {
        output += m[0];
    }
} while (m);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Yo thank u so much, I included everything you mentioned in your answer but instead of setting a variable input I just used the function input "string"

Comment: oh and I used a constructor RegExp instead ^____^

Comment: I also have trouble understanding your if / while loops, why do you use variables on their own?

Comment: @evan My second answer just uses a regex iterator to find all matches in the input string.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of matching all the capital letters you can replace all the characters that are not capital letters, here is an example:

```js
function capitalSentence(s) {
  return s.replace(/[^A-Z]/g, "");
}

console.log(["The Cat In The Hat", "And I Think to Myself What a Wonderful World"].map(capitalSentence))
```